# Alternative ways to select DOM elements in case common methods don't work

Tags: javascript, dom

I consider a DOM element "hard to be selected" if it fills 5 terms:

1. It doesn't have any identifiers whatsoever (ID's, Classes or unique attributes).
2. Its `Xpath` is created dynamically in each server creation of a webpage.
3. It's one of many elements of the same tag (say, `div`), and the number of these is also dynamic, so a specific item reference like `document.querySelector('div')[322]`, will be principally ineffective.
4. It is a bit frustrating to target by the HTML alone given that the road from a parent element with an `ID` is quite large (like 25-30 elements). It's also impossible in case the ID is created dynamically.
5. Other elements share the same `textContent` of the element (though these will appear on viewport only if you'll open accordions that contain them).

### What's left?

I understand that the only thing left in such rare case is to condition with these aspects together:

- textContent.
- Availability in viewport (for an element with unique content when **above the fold**, it would be easier).

And that also won't be always perfect.

Out of curiosity. What else is left to uniquely identify such elements?

Edit: I am asking this on sites, not mine - I cannot edit their Server side code.

Comment: The best way is to add unique identifiers or classes on the server side where these get generated.

Comment: The answer is easy ... you're writing your HTML the wrong way if you encounter issues like this.

Comment: I mean only to cases where the user doesn't control the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing some sort of browser test automation for an existing website?
I've found the sanest way of selecting DOM elements is to introduce a layer of business logic.

So for example, if we have an accordian that happens to have an ID, I might start of doing a selector for the accordian and then storing all the child elements into an array. I would then iterate through that array and try and find the element i was looking for based on some sort of logic.

This will be super inefficient but at least you can add comments and sane function names to seperate out what you are looking for from how you are looking for it.

Comment: Thumb up: Targeting the accordion button and put all accordion children is a good approach indeed. Please share a code example for how you would actually put all its children into an array. I mean, if I target the button that opens the accordion with `document.querySelector('')', what's next?

Comment: There is only one problem: What if the ID if the UL list is created dynamically?...

Comment: i only used the accordian id as an example. Within the webpage there would surely be some unique elements that you can target. For example, you might know that the accordian will always be the fifth ul element from the body. The general idea is to add a business rule layer so that you have a place to apply some comments and sanity.